# for the greater good

Tags: meaning

In a sentence: "We arrive after a fraught journey, which I undertake begrudgingly, for the greater good, since I am clearly not the maddest person in the bus," what does "for the greater good" mean in connection with the following?

Comment: Since you haven't provided any context regarding the situation being described, it's anyone's guess what it means here.

Answer (score 3):

[The greater good](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the%20greater%20good&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthe%20greater%20good%3B%2Cc0):

> - Is a common expression which refers to the fact that you are doing something  that most likely will not benefit you but many people, a community or even the human race according to the context.
> - The expression  is often used in political, religious or philosophical contexts.

- In your sentence, the author is saying that he undertook the difficult journey  for the benefit of all those who made the trip.